# Creating a match policy rules for a specific header is not contains

Tags: soapui, ibm-datapower

I am trying to creating an MPGW processing rule, here i want to create a match policy which will allow incoming messages only when a specific header is not present in it, but i couldn't able to find a condition or PCRE expression which can achieve this ? any script or anything possible to achieve this

I tried in Datapower 10.0.1 version,
IBM Doc portal also didn't find any.

Here i want to create default match for some messages and creating separate for those which specific header is not present in incoming messages the it will be get match and route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the match rule is not suitable, your only option is to add a transform, either Gatewayscript or XSLT.
GWS is easier to use for dynamic rules.
You can then, either populate context variables and use a conditional rule, or call another processing rule from the script.